# What is the proper encapsulation syntax?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I have publication and library two classes and in publication class. How to manipulate(as encapsulation) genre, media, and target_age, If I want them to be separate classes. It's not class inside another class. 
The genre have more type's as (fiction, non-fiction, self-help, performance) as well as media and age. I have done my research I'm serchin for the proper syntax for it.

```
class Publication {    
  private:
    string title;
    string authore;
    string copyright;
    Genre genre;
    Media media;
    Age target_age;
    string isbn;
    bool checked_out;
    string patron_name;
    string patron_phone;

  public:
    void check_out(string patron_name, string patron_phone ){}
    void check_in(){}
    bool is_checked_out(){}
    string to_string(){}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to encapsulate is to keep everything private. Create constant getters for stuff that might be read from the outside, and initialize everything in the constructor. After all, things like author/title/etc. should not ever change for an instance of a real book right? Have a look at the following snippet:

```
class Publication {    
  private:
    string _title;
    string _author;
    Genre _genre;

  public:
    void check_out(string patron_name, string patron_phone );
    void check_in();
    bool is_checked_out() const;

    string to_string() const;
    string get_title() const { return _title; }
    string get_author() const { return _author; }
    const Genre& get_genre() const { return _genre; }


    Publication(string author, string title, Genre genre) : _author(auth), _title(title), _genre(genre)
    { }
};
```

Comment: I have done the same thing. I'm using setters and getters for to private variables. My problem is how to manipulate genre, media and age if they are class objects in private section for publication class?

Comment: The point of encapsulation is that you don't want them to be manipulated with... otherwise make them public and don't call it encapsulation. In your example (if I understand it right) you don't have any reason to change a genre of an existing publication... why would you have to do that? Note, that class `Publication` can still manipulate the instance of `Genre`, but nobody from the outside can... that is the whole point of encapsulation...

Comment: @ Kupto Ok, I did understood your point. Now how should I implement genre with fiction, non-fiction, self-help, and performance. Another thing which is confusing me. What is the use of it in program.

Comment: I would use an `enum` to implement genre.